# v1 Token request does not work (Marketing Cloud) and pulls a NULL result

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I am simply trying to run this v1 Auth request access token in a cloud page but keep getting a Null result. What is wrong with my code below??

```
var client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var client_Secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
  // Get Auth Token
var token = getToken(client_id, client_Secret);
Write(Stringify(token));

function getToken(client_id, client_Secret) {
                            var endpoint = "https://QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v1/requestToken";
                            var payload = Stringify({
                            "clientId": client_id,
                            "clientSecret": client_Secret
                            });
                    
                            var content = [0];
                            var accessToken = "";                
                            try {
                              var statusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(endpoint, 'application/json', payload, null, null, content);                
                              accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content[0]).accessToken;                          
                              return accessToken;
                            } catch (err) {
                              var error = "Error getting access token from REST API. Error message: " + Stringify(err);
                              Variable.SetValue("@errorMessage", error);
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: is your installed package an legacy package or a new package?

Comment: oh damn! it was a new package. I have just attempted to run it with a legacy package and it works! 
Thanks EazyE :D

Answer (score 3):

TO recap the comment above

the v1/token route is only used with the legacy installed package types

if you have an new(enhanced) installed package you need to use the v2 token route

Comment: How do I know if it's a legacy package or an enhanced one? And it seems in [Salesforce official doc here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/create-integration-legacy.html) says that we cannot create a Legacy package anymore

Comment: if you go to the installed package you won't be able to license it to any other BU

Comment: Got it, I just need to look through the installed packages from 2019 to find them, and their Licenses tab would show this: `You cannot license this package to any other business units at this time.`